# Simple Fluid Simulation won't work

Tags: fluid-simulation

Just tried Blender out for the first time. I wanted to animate a fluid but when I bake it nothing happens. I would really appreciate if someone could have a quick view over my File to see what I did wrong.
Here is the File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zphmslbdgaebrm3/winewassserthick.blend%40?dl=0

Comment: In your case you can't use the Volume initialization type volume for your obstacle. Blender will see the fluid as inside a closed object. You need to use "shell" or "both".

Comment: Thank you, with "both" it wouldn't work but after this I tried shell and it finally worked. Thanks a lot.